# Output audio with Bluetooth and speaker at same time

Tags: audio, headphones, bluetooth-audio, headset

I want to watch a film with my friends
on my Xiaomi/Redmi7/Android9. I have Bluetooth headset and he have normal Headphones (with cable).

How can I output the sound on BT and AUX at same time?

Comment: Which Android version is installed?

Comment: Android 9 is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, smartphones does not support the audio output to Bluetooth and to speaker at the same time. But some models support output to more than 1 Bluetooth device.

check this lifewire tutorial https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-connect-multiple-bluetooth-speakers-4173788